# На каком сервере надо реализовывать MVC на PHP?

Tags: php, mvc

Начал изучать MVC. Суть данного шаблона проектирования ясна. Пытаюсь освоить это по видеоурокам, где в конечном итоге получается собственный фреймворк.

Проблема заключается в том, что, переписав весь код, создав такую же структуру папок, у меня ничего не работает. Тогда я начал думать, что делаю не так.

Обнаружил: все авторы видеороликов после создания структуры папок, файлов, сначала заливают их на удаленный сервер(при этом не рассказывают зачем, как это делается), и только потом начинают кодить. Я же продолжал все делать на localhost. Таким образом видоизменяется адресная строка. В моем случае это:"localhost/dir/dir/dir/index.php", а в их "myframework.loc/index.php". Может ли это быть проблемой?

Кроме localhost ничего нет. Решил сделать ftp со своим локальным IP. Через Netbeans пытаюсь выгрузить папки и файлы, но выгрузка не происходит. Ошибка 550.

Не могу разобраться с этим вопросом уже месяц. Не знаю, как продвигаться дальше. А сразу изучать готовый фреймворк не хочется, т.к. надо понять, как он пишется руками. Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный алгоритм действий при разработке MVC на PHP.

Comment: Поставьте себе на локальный комп сервер W(M|L)AMP https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP (только Денвер не используйте, он давно не обновлялся).

Comment: У меня LAMP и стоит. Т.е. я могу не заморачиваться с удаленными серверами и реализовывать MVC прям на LAMP? В чем тогда причина не той работы, что в видеоуроках? Я решил, что из-за разницы в виде адресных строк.

Comment: вы бы лучше взяли какой-нибудь известный фреймворк и его изучали. толку куда больше было бы, чем изучать нечто неработающее по видео урокам.

Comment: Проблема в том, что они используют маршрутизацию, а ты нет. Сервер тут вообще не причем

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, так я также, как и они, писал роутер и роуты.

Comment: teran, просто неоднократно встречал мнение, что сначала нужно самому написать собственный фреймворк, cms и так далее, прежде чем начать изучать уже существующий фреймворк.

Comment: Если вы писали роутер, то проверяйте какие файлы подгружаются при вызове URLок через require или include, и выясняйте несоответствие в правилах путей и Вашего кода роутинга.